# Terminate current command and move to next command in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I've created a batch file

```
@echo off
Mkdir c:\asp
Copy * c:\asp\
Cd/
CD c:\asp
Dir
Pause
```

If I want to terminate the copy command and move to dir command how can I do so?

Comment: so you wish to terminate "Copy * c:\asp\" in the middle and skip two commands , "Cd/  & CD c:\asp"? Is "Copy * c:\asp\" long running command?

Answer (score 0):

Since **CTRL + C** will terminate overall script and not a single command , I suggest to launch *Copy* command in a separate CMD window without **/WAIT** and then use label to go to your desired command ,

```
@echo off  
Mkdir c:\asp  
START Copy *  c:\asp\

GOTO SABIRLABEL

Cd/   
CD c:\asp  
:SABIRLABEL

Dir

Pause
```

You can then use **CTRL + C** in second window to terminate copy if its long running process.

Also you can make `GOTO` conditional on some variable value if you don't always wish to skip those two commands.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "CHOICE" (available under DOS in Win 8.1)

@echo off
Mkdir c:\asp

HERE goes CHOICE///// etc...

Copy * c:\asp\
Cd/
CD c:\asp
Dir
Pause

Example:
OPEN DOS BOX...
TYPE CHOICE /?

See this...
C:\Windows\system32>choice /?

CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]

Description:
    This tool allows users to select one item from a list
    of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

NOTE:
   The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
   key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice
   listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.
   If the user presses a key that is not a valid choice, the tool
   sounds a warning beep. If tool detects an error condition,
   it returns an ERRORLEVEL value of 255. If the user presses
   CTRL+BREAK or CTRL+C, the tool returns an ERRORLEVEL value
   of 0. When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list
   them in decreasing order.

Examples:
   CHOICE /?
   CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
   CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y
   CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
   CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."